# Apache not executing PHP on CentOS 7 in browser

Tags: linux, centos, apache-http-server, php

I've installed the following:

```
[root@localhost conf.d]# yum list installed | grep 'http'
httpd.x86_64                     2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1          @updates
httpd-tools.x86_64               2.4.6-80.el7.centos.1          @updates
[root@localhost conf.d]# yum list installed | grep 'php'
php72.x86_64                     1.0-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe
php72-php-cli.x86_64             7.2.11-1.el7.remi              @remi-safe
php72-php-common.x86_64          7.2.11-1.el7.remi              @remi-safe
php72-php-json.x86_64            7.2.11-1.el7.remi              @remi-safe
php72-runtime.x86_64             1.0-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe
```

PHP works fine already via CLI

```
[root@localhost conf.d]# php -v
PHP 7.2.11 (cli) (built: Oct 10 2018 08:49:35) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Apache also works fine

```
[root@localhost modules]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Jun 27 2018 13:48:59
```

My issues is Apache doesn't execute PHP and just triggers a download of the PHP file in the browser.

Note: This is on Vagrant running `centos/7` box.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you loading PHP in `httpd.conf`? For example on Windows `LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php5apache2_4.dll"`

Comment: I don't see that line. Actually `ls /etc/httpd/modules/` doesn't show anything about PHP. It seems there was no PHP module installed for Apache. Any ideas how to install it?

Comment: Not really. I use Windows not Linux. And installed [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) for convenience.

Comment: @IMB did you found any solution for this problem i have similar problem like this please help if you have solved this issue

Comment: @MohitJain see my answer below

Answer (score 10):

For those who care, apparently the default `php72` don't install the `mod_php`.

`php72-php` should be used instead.

So I just simply reinstalled PHP using `php72-php` instead  of `php72` and restarted Apache.

(answer found from https://serverfault.com/a/728663/75899)

Comment: Perfect. This solves the issue in centOS.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am working with Amazon workspaces with centOS and the problem was solved with:

```
yum install php73-php
```